# how to integrate and Test a project created using Hyperledger Fabric version 2.3.1 using Hyperledger Caliper?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, caliper

i'm currently working on blockchain based document verification system.the system is created using hyperledger fabric version 2.3.1.
i want to test the performance of the system(Average Latency, Throughput) using Hyperledger Caliper.
my question is,
which version of Hyperledger Caliper is suitable for fabric version 2.3.1?and which node version i must install?
how to test my system created using Hyperledger Fabric version 2.3.1 using caliper locally?
i'm new for blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hyperledger caliper 0.4.2 (latest version at time of writing). It's only tested on Node 10 so I would use that (it may work with later versions of Node).

When you bind a SUT you have a choice of 1.4 or 2.2 both of these can drive a fabric 2.3 network (caliper uses a different version of node-sdk under the covers). I would recommend using 2.2 though as that version is the officially support SDK version for 2.3

take a look at the tutorial here to get you started https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/